# NVidia CUDA toolkit 7.5.27 failing to install on OS X

Tags: macos, cuda, nvidia

Downloading the CUDA toolkit DMG works, but the installer fails with a cryptic "package manifest parsing error" error after selecting packages.

Running the installer from the command line using the binary inside fails in a similar manner. The log file at /var/log/cuda_installer.log basically says the same:

```
Apr 28 18:16:10  CUDAMacOSXInstaller[58493] : Awoken from nib!
Apr 28 18:16:10  CUDAMacOSXInstaller[58493] : Switched to local mode.
Apr 28 18:16:24  CUDAMacOSXInstaller[58493] : Package manifest parsing error!
Apr 28 18:16:24  CUDAMacOSXInstaller[58493] : Package manifest parsing error!
Apr 28 18:16:24  CUDAMacOSXInstaller[58493] : Package manifest parsing error!
```

I have a prior version of cuda 7.5 installed, which (a while ago) was done through the same process without error.

(OS X 10.11, GeForce GT750M)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The phrase "Package manifest parsing error" produced zero hits on Google before, so hopefully this answer helps others.

I spoke to an NVidia dev about this, and apparently there is a known issue for version 7.5.27 on OS X. Having more than one CUDA installed DMG mounted will cause any installer to have this issue.

Unmounting all but one DMG solves this issue. It will likely be fixed in a future release of the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: For me, the network installation give me the error, the local one just closes. Unmounting all DMGs and starting over with the local version worked! Thx!

Comment: How do I find all my mounted DMGs?

Comment: Open a finder window and they'll be on the left under "Devices". Alternately, you can just take a look on your Desktop and they should be there. If you're a terminal person, `ls /Volumes` or `mount` will work.

Comment: @pekapa I had the exact same situation, and now solution thanks to you.

Comment: For me only worked with local installer and all dmgs unmounted. Copied the installer to a local folder first

Comment: This is comically awful. What a ridiculous thing to happen, thanks for finding the solution!

Answer (score 14):

I’m in the same boat.
These steps solved this issue.

1. Unmount all DMG
2. Mount only one "Local Installer" DMG
3. Launch Installer and complete procedure

Network Installer didn't work in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall the version of CUDA I had installed previously by running `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA7.5/bin/uninstall***.pl` before installing the new version.